# Easy way to collapse trailing dimensions of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

In Matlab, I can do the following:

```
X = randn(25,25,25);
size(X(:,:))

ans = 
    25   625
```

I often find myself wanting to quickly collapse the trailing dimensions of an array, and do not know how to do this in numpy.

I know I can do this:

```
In [22]: x = np.random.randn(25,25,25)
In [23]: x = x.reshape(x.shape[:-2] + (-1,))
In [24]: x.shape
Out[24]: (25, 625)
```

but `x.reshape(x.shape[:-2] + (-1,))` is a *lot* less concise (and requires more information about `x`) than simply doing `x(:,:)`.

I've obviously tried the analogous numpy indexing, but that does not work as desired:

```
In [25]: x = np.random.randn(25,25,25)
In [26]: x[:,:].shape
Out[26]: (25, 25, 25)
```

Any hints on how to collapse the trailing dimensions of an array in a concise manner?

Edit: note that I'm after the resulting array itself, not just its shape. I merely use `size()` and `x.shape` in the above examples to indicate what the array is like.

Comment: On a side note, your example is incorrect... `x.shape[:-2]` would yield an empty tuple. (Adding `-1` to it means the array would be "flattened" into a 15625-length array.) I'm guessing you meant `x.shape[0]`?

Comment: @JoeKington: It *is* correct (try it). `x.shape[:-2]` returns `x.shape` up to (but not including) the second-to-last element. So for a 3D-array `x`, it returns just the first element of `x.shape`. I used `[:-2]` rather than `[0]` because I'm looking for a general solution that works for all ND arrays where N>2.

Comment: @ElkeSpaak - Right. I wasn't thinking clearly.

Comment: Does that MATLAB work on a 4 or 5d matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is supposed to happen with a 4d or higher?

```
octave:7> x=randn(25,25,25,25);
octave:8> size(x(:,:))
ans =
      25   15625
```

Your `(:,:)` reduces it to 2 dimensions, combining the last ones.  The last dimension is where MATLAB automatically adds and collapses dimensions.

```
In [605]: x=np.ones((25,25,25,25))

In [606]: x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1).shape  # like Joe's
Out[606]: (25, 15625)

In [607]: x.reshape(x.shape[:-2]+(-1,)).shape
Out[607]: (25, 25, 625)
```

Your `reshape` example does something different from MATLAB, it just collapses the last 2.  Collapsing it down to 2 dimensions like MATLAB is a simpler expression.

The MATLAB is concise simply because your needs match it's assumptions.  The `numpy` equivalent isn't quite so concise, but gives you more control

For example to keep the last dimension, or combine dimensions 2 by 2:

```
In [608]: x.reshape(-1,x.shape[-1]).shape
Out[608]: (15625, 25)
In [610]: x.reshape(-1,np.prod(x.shape[-2:])).shape
Out[610]: (625, 625)
```

What's the equivalent MATLAB?

```
octave:24> size(reshape(x,[],size(x)(2:end)))
ans =
15625      25
octave:31> size(reshape(x,[],prod(size(x)(3:end))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find it a bit more concise to modify the `shape` attribute directly.  For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(25, 25, 25)
x.shape = x.shape[0], -1

print x.shape
print x
```

This is functionally equivalent to `reshape` (in the sense of data ordering, etc).  Obviously, it still requires the same information about `x`'s shape, but it is a more concise way of handling the reshape.

Comment: It has the added "benefit" that, if the reshaping cannot be done without a copy, it will raise an error, so I often use it as a form of asserting that my code is efficiently using memory.

Comment: why not `x.shape = *(x.shape[:-2]), -1` in case `x` has dimension higher than 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.hstack` :

```
>>> np.hstack(x).shape
(25, 625)
```

> `np.hstack` ake a sequence of arrays and stack them horizontally to make a single array.

Comment: That's an interesting use of `np.hstack`! However, it does not yield the same result as `x.reshape(x.shape[:-2] + (-1,))`, so should be used with caution. Thinking about it a bit further, what I believe is going on is that `np.hstack` treats the *first* dimension of the array as the iterable dimension, and thus returns the same as `np.hstack(x[0,:,:],x[1,:,:],...)`. I need functionality that leaves the first dimension untouched (i.e. all data previously in x[0,:,:] is now in x[0,:]), as is the case for the Matlab version.

Comment: Do you want a new array or just want its shape?

Comment: I'm after the contents of the array itself, the shape is just for illustration. I edited the original question to make this more clear.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak so can you add a minimal example of your expected result?